# What is the analogue to the sword fighting style in Wheel of Time?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

The protagonist of the series, Rand al'Thor, is described as a master swordsman and fights with a sword pretty often through the series. The sword design sounds very much like a katana in design (see: http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Blademaster#Sword_of_a_Blademaster) which in my mind makes me think it would be like kendo, but the use of forms (such as 'Parting the Silk', 'Heron Wading in the Rushes') seems like a kung-fu reference. What fighting style would Rand's style look like, as described in the book?

Comment: Absent any actual images from the books, I am not sure this is answerable. The names (as you state) suggest this is more of a kung-fu/Chinese style, as does the "Flame and the Void" practice, but that isn't concrete enough to make a definitive association.

Comment: That seems like a pretty solid answer to me. Shall I just close this out then?

Comment: I don't know. I have not read the books in aeons, so I don't remember if the style is described enough in the books themselves to make that determination.

Comment: I pinged a WoT expert to give an opinion. :)

Comment: The blades sound somewhat like katanas, if only because they tend toward single edged and slightly curving.  But they also have cross guards unlike katanas, and frankly single edged and slightly curving could describe any number of sabers and scimitars as well.

Comment: Heron swords are evocative of katanas, but you're right that the real world equivalent would be something like a saber.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### They were mainly of his own creation, taking inspiration from Japanese and European styles

Searching [Theoryland for Sword Forms](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt=%27sword%20forms%27) and [Sword Fighting](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=sword%20fighting) there are a few results from interviews given by Robert Jordan that explain his inspiration for creating the forms of fighting and the naming of the forms in the series.

Under the tag [Sword Forms](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt=%27sword%20forms%27) Robert explains that the forms are based mainly on Taekwondo and Karate, and based off fighting styles from Japan and Europe:

> **QUESTION**
>   
>   Are the sword forms based on reality?
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN**
>   
>   Sort of based on Taekwondo and Karate—but from books, not experience.
>   
> <sub>[Theoryland - Sword Forms](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt=%27sword%20forms%27)</sub>

And that the forms are based off his imagination:

> **CLAYTON FROM HUTCHINSON**
>   
>   First, I thoroughly enjoy the Wheel of Time series. Is there an actual form of martial arts that inspired the "sword forms", and are the forms you mention in the books part of this art or are they you own creation?
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN**
>   
>   The sword forms described in the book are my own creation, but they are based in part on the Japanese art of the sword, and also on fencing as it developed, when it was well on its way to becoming a martial art as we define them today (when it was developing in the Renaissance).
>   
> <sub>[Theoryland - Sword Forms](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt=%27sword%20forms%27)</sub>

And he also answers a question about the naming of the forms:

> **MATHEW-E**
>   
>   Sir, I truly enjoy reading the sword fighting scenes, could you give us some background information on where you got the names for the various forms used?
>
> **ROBERT JORDAN**
>   
>   The names are creations of my own, but they're based on Japanese and Chinese techniques and European techniques pre-gunpowder.
>   
> <sub>[Theoryland - Sword Forms](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt=%27sword%20forms%27)</sub>